# CI helper variable is not accessing in view file

Tags: php, codeigniter

I load a helper file and it is included successfully

The constants variable in helper file such as 
Define("FIELD_VALID", "valid");
If i echo FIELD_VALID in view file...it works

But there is assigned variable in helper file such as
$strSite="http://www.mysite.com/";
If i echo $strSite in view file, it prints nothing

Hoping for the answer
Thanks.

Comment: Probably there's a better, more organized way to achieve this. If you're trying to access some variables, would it work to just have a custom configuration file? http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do would be much better accomplished with a custom config file. Look at this: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/config.html

Comment: actually i was implementing sagepay payment API, and i put the API file to helper, that file contains some variables assigned....i don't want to cut the variables from there and put into config....any solution for it?

Comment: @Frozenfire You should make it a library instead, then

Comment: @Frozenfire, if you do a Google search for "sagepay codeigniter library", there have been a bunch created already. It shouldn't be hard to edit one to perform the functionality that you're looking for.